# reactive-banana reactimate to retrieve the widget textCtrl Value like textCtrlGetValue

Tags: haskell, reactive-programming, reactive-banana

I would like to retrieve the widget value.

In the following, pressing the button b  retrieve  s_in and print it , in native wxhaskell.

```
b <- button f [text:= "print text in console", 
               on command := textCtrlGetValue s_in >>= putStrLn]
```

I like to do the same on reactive-banana , but in the following, I get "ff" and not the textCtrlGetValue of s_in2

```
s_in  <- textCtrl f  []
s_in2 <- textCtrl f  []

b <- button f [text:= "print text in console", 
               on command := textCtrlGetValue s_in >>= putStrLn]



let networkDescription :: forall t. Frameworks t => Moment t ()
    networkDescription = do

    b_in  <- behaviorText s_in "init"
    b_in2 <- behaviorText s_in2 "ff"
    e_butt <- event0 b command


    -- I need an event, triggered by the button, and filled by the b_in2, 

    sink s_in2 [text :== id <$> b_in]     

    reactimate $   (\x -> putStrLn x)  <$> b_in2 <@ e_butt
```

the sink updates well sin_2 after s_in .
but the following reactimate line does not get me the textCtrlGetValue of s_in/ b_in I wish to get . how can I "get" it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior obtained with the `behaviorText` function will only react to changes that the *user* made to the edit box. It does *not* include *programmatic* changes, like those performed with the `sink` function.

Distinguishing between user events and programmatic events is essential for writing responsive UI elements that have [bidirectional data flow](http://apfelmus.nfshost.com/blog/2012/03/29-frp-three-principles-bidirectional-gui.html). See the [CurrencyConverter example](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Reactive-banana/Examples#CurrencyConverter) for a demonstration.

If you want to keep track of programmatic changes, I recommend to stay "within the FRP world", i.e. to use the behavior `b_out = id <$> b_in` instead of trying to read the text from the widget.

(By the way, `id <$> x = x`.)

Comment: First thanks for the quick answer. I did noticed the bidirectional dataflow, and wondered why it did not loop, at that time ! Now, I know, thanks ! I did not noticed this important separation of concepts before. Now another topic I crossed ( [documented here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758975/separating-state-for-a-model-and-gui-io-wx-stack-or-frp) ) is how can I have a Model and a GUI interact, bearing in mind the model is not GUI or WX specific ( _ the graph in the example is not the graph of widget dependencies (typical in FRP) , but the graph of the diagram to represent_ )